# Unable to invoke select event dynamically on tab in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have created tabs by using jQuery API and have bound one event handler on the click of second tab by using the below code:

```
    $('#tabs').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
        refreshRemoveUI(event,ui);
    });

function refreshRemoveUI(event,ui) {
    if(ui.index==1){
        $.get('FrontServlet?operation=getAllQues',function(data) {
            var html = "";
            var questionsNum = data.split(",");
            if(questionsNum!="") {
                html += '<br/><input type=checkbox name=removeAllQuestionId id=removeAllQuestionId onclick="toggleAll(this.checked)"/> Select/Deselect All<br/>';
                for(var i=0;i<questionsNum.length;i++){
                    html += '<br/><input type=checkbox name=removeQuestionId id=removeQuestionId /> ' + questionsNum[i];
                }
                $('#remove').show();
            } else {
                $('#remove').hide();
                html = 'No question available in quiz';
            }
            $('#removequestions').html(html);
            });         
    }
}
```

I want to invoke the same bind event on the completion of ajax request too and following is what I have tried but no luck:

```
    $.get('FrontServlet?operation=remove&position='+val, function(data) {
        $("#tabs li.ui-state-default:nth(1)").trigger("select");

    });
```

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Just doing some guessing here, as I don't thoroughly know the matter and without a working sample it's a whole lot of work to reproduce the problem, but shouldn't you do `[..].trigger('tabselect')` instead of `[..].trigger('select')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No suggestions seem to work
I had to refactor my code as below:

```
    $('#tabs').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.index==1){
            refreshRemoveUI(event,ui);
        }

    });

            $.get('FrontServlet?operation=remove&position='+val, function(data) {
                refreshRemoveUI();

            });

function refreshRemoveUI(event,ui) {
        $.get('FrontServlet?operation=getAllQues',function(data) {
            var html = "";
            var questionsNum = data.split(",");
            if(questionsNum!="") {
                html += '<br/><input type=checkbox name=removeAllQuestionId id=removeAllQuestionId onclick="toggleAll(this.checked)"/> Select/Deselect All<br/>';
                for(var i=0;i<questionsNum.length;i++){
                    html += '<br/><input type=checkbox name=removeQuestionId id=removeQuestionId /> ' + questionsNum[i];
                }
                $('#remove').show();
            } else {
                $('#remove').hide();
                html = 'No question available in quiz';
            }
            $('#removequestions').html(html);
            });         
}
```

Now I am getting the results I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to invoke the tab (second tab in this case) to be selected after the ajax load. Why don't you use this in your ajax call?

```
$('#tabs').tabs("select", 1);
```

Hope that helps!